# Looking for proper behavior

Tags: django, django-models

my models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=160)

class Answer(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=260)    
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

And if i want all answers related to particular question, but hiting database as little as possible, should i use `select_related` like that:

```
 q = Question.objects.select_related(depth=1).get(id=id)            
 answers = q.answer_set.all()
```

or just:

```
 q = Question.objects.get(id=id)            
 answers = q.answer_set.all()
```

?

Answer (score 1):

For answering this type of question, consider installing the [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar). It provides information on all DB queries performed to process a request, including the amount of time each query takes.

So install the toolbar in your project, and browse to a page on your site that performs the query. Click on the toolbar to see query information. Try it both ways to see which is better.

Comment: Nice looking stuff. Good to know that something like it exist. Thank You.